# Angular ui-router: how call $stateChangeStart with state.go({notify:false})?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular SPA with ui-router. For infinite scroll I'm using

```
$state.go('someStateWithPagination', {page: page+1}, {notify: false, reload: false})
```

But now I need to integrate Google Analytics. and I thought that I can use
`$stateChangeStart`, but this event couldn't be triggered in case of `{notify: false}`, because ui-router didn't call new state. Can you advice me any solution for GA integration?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Angulartics](http://angulartics.github.io/) which tracks navigation by default as mentioned in their documentation in below image

[image]